# Flutter define and use global variable from SharedPreferences

Tags: flutter, dart

My rest service return some value eg. username and job.

After get data from api I save username and job to SharedPreferences.

How after add to SharedPreferences set this value as global variable and use on other page?

some like this eg. page.dart

**Text(MySharedPreferences().username.toString());**

```
//Set to SharedPreferences
setToSharedPreferences(String username, String job) async {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    sharedPreferences.setStringList('mySp',[username.toString(), job.toString()]);
}
```

Or some other solution to save value from api as global variable without SharedPreferences?

Comment: you also can get that value from shared preference in any screen.

Comment: @SumitaNaiya Yes I know, but on all page I must import sharedPreferences and add SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance().......

Comment: please write a seperate class for shared_preference.

Comment: no thats not the way you can make instance of shared preference in main.dart file as globale make it preference instance in main.dart file and use this instance variable in any screen

Comment: I recommend use the  [get_storage package](https://pub.dev/packages/get_storage), it can be use to get values in synchronous way. It's not difficult to use and you can use it with global variables.